# Drop down list for ldap users "department"

Tags: php, ldap

I'm still new in PHP, How do i "GROUP BY" all "department" in Active Directory and make it a drop down list selection on PHP? I have already tried to list down that string, but it to many duplicates "department". Thank you.

** UPDATE! This is my code.

```
//FILTER FOR USER ONLY
$object_filter  ='(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))';
$ldap_search    = ldap_search($ldap_connect, $ou, $object_filter);

//SORT NAME FROM A - Z
ldap_sort  ($ldap_connect  , $ldap_search  , "cn");

$ldap_get_entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connect, $ldap_search);  

// No information found, bad user
if($ldap_get_entries['count'] == 0) return false;

echo '<select>';
for ($i=0; $i < $ldap_get_entries["count"]; $i++){
    $department = $ldap_get_entries[$i]["department"][0];
    echo '<option value=' . $department . '>' . $department . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: what you try , add your codes

Comment: In Stack Overflow, no one can give you readymade code for your problem. you should do it by yourself and if the problem exists in your code then show the code in question. someone will help you.

Comment: sorry I'm new here, how can i put my code here?